# How to create declaration file for a module which exports function?

Tags: typescript

I need to create declaration file for a JavaScript module which exports function. The JavaScript module looks like this:

```
module.exports = hello

function hello() { console.log('Hello') }
```

I tried creating declaration file different ways:

```
export function hello(): void
```

```
export default function hello(): void
```

```
declare function hello(): void

export = hello
```

Nothing works with any kind of imports:

```
import hello from './filename'
```

```
import { hello } from './filename'
```

How to create declaration file for such modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're dealing with is a Default Export in commonJS:

```js
modules.exports = hello
```

In your declaration `.d.ts`file you shouldn't reimplement the function behavior like you seem to do. You just want to declare the typing for it. I believe this would do it:

```js
declare function hello(): void
export = hello
```

You also always can use TS Playground in the .D.TS tab to use the feature that TS generates declarations for you:
[image: TS Playground screen capture]

check more in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

Comment: Sorry. Implementation was a mistake in the question. The point is: `export default` isn't working.

Comment: My mistake. try just `export = hello` like I edited in my answer above.